# \renewenvironment for \begin{comment}

Tags: environments, preamble

In my document, there are several comments like

```
\begin{comment}
comment
\end{comment}
```

As the comment environment doesn't work, e.g., in footnotes, I want to replace it by the "note" environment.

I tried the following:

```
\renewenvironment{comment}{\begin{note}}{\end{note}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{version}
\excludeversion{note}

\renewenvironment{comment}{\begin{note}}{\end{note}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
before%
\begin{comment}
comment content
\end{comment}
after


\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{version}
\excludeversion{note}

\renewenvironment{comment}{\note\ignorespaces}{\endnote\ignorespacesafterend}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
before%
\begin{comment}
comment content
\end{comment}
after


\end{document}
```

Inside environment we usually don't use `\begin{}` and `\end{}` ... but their equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! There is only one remaining problem: There is now a space. This can be a probelm if a comment is put between a word and a dot.

Comment: @Fabian check edited version ... But please consider accepting some of the answers already given to your previous questions... Questions with no accepted answers in such "forums" lowers the "actual value" of the "forum"...

Comment: @Fabian Thanks for accepting... but I meant about your old posts ... Anyway ... When you find the time consider accepting some answers of your old posts that you think they solved the problem, or even adding an answer yourself with the way you solved the problem ... (if really solved),